# como criar uma app em Android que tens de apertar no icone da aplicação e ele liga para um unico numero

Tags: android

Eu estou iniciando em desenvolvimento mobile e gostaria de criar uma app, na qual pudesse registrar um numero e sempre que clicar no icone do programa ele fazia uma chamada para esse mesmo numero

Comment: Olá, bem vinda ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Está claro o que vc quer/precisa fazer, mas não está clara qual é a sua dúvida ou dificuldade específica. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Você já tem uma resposta que explica como fazer uma ligação para um número. Então, se mudar a sua pergunta pra ser específica nesse sentido, eu retiro o meu voto pra fechar. :)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você cria o **botão:**

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  String phno="10digits";

  Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(phno));
  startActivity(i);
}
});
```

Fiz esse **exemplo** mas não quer dizer que seja necessariamente dessa forma.

De seguida, temos que dar permissão à **manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

E dentro da **activity:**

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Embora você não tenha expressado da forma **mais** correta o seu problema, à uns tempos atrás eu tive esse mesmo problema, pesquisei por ele e resolvi-o da forma que indiquei. 
**Qualquer** dúvida disponha.